# Экранизация процента загрузки

Tags: css, php, html, javascript

У меня есть скрипт, который должен обрабатывать некий файл, размером, предположим, в 100 000 строк. Все как и должно быть, располагается в массиве и действует при помощи цикла

```
while($i < count($file)) {
...
$i++;
}
```

Но я столкнулся с проблемой. Как мне вывести на экран процент прохода скриптом файла? Я набросал код, который выводит последовательно процент загрузки, но мне нужно, чтобы это выводилось при помощи js в строку стилей элемента <div>

Comment: Как я понимаю, вам нужно передовать от сервера на клиент процесс обработки?

Comment: Да, верно.

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = count($file);

while($i < $count) {
    if(i%10 == 0) {
        echo $i*100/$count . ' процентов<br />';
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Это линейный вывод. у меня сейчас точно так-же

Comment: Эм, не совсем пойму, что вам еще нужно. Или у вас не получается обрабатывать данные с помощью JavaScript? Ну тут не сложнее моего поста: 

     <script>
     function getPersent(val) {
          document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = val + '%';
     }
     </script>

А в цикле поменять:

     echo  "getPersent('".$i*100/$count."')";

Comment: http://clip2net.com/clip/m110674/thumb640/1370501883-clip-5kb.png 
В итоге такое чудо.
А требуется, чтобы выводилась новая строка на месте старой.

Comment: @SnikersSurgut, наверно вы добавляете новый элемент с очередным значением, а надо в определенном элементе изменять текущее значение, что в общем-то вам и показал @lampa - **.innerHTML**

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно.

Есть файл `loadable.php`, который делает доооолгий процесс:

```
<?

$from = 0;
$to = 10000;
$progress_update = 100;
header('Content-Length: '.ceil(($to - $from) / $progress_update), true, 200);

set_time_limit($to + 10);

for ($i = $from; $i < $to; $i++)
    {
    usleep(100);

    if ($i % $progress_update == 0)
        {
        echo ' ';
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        }
    }

die(' ');

?>
```

И есть файл, который обращаясь за файлом `loadable.php`, вызывает этот долгий процесс асинхронным запросом и показывает прогресс выполнения:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress id="progress" min="0" max="1" value="0"></progress>
<script>

var timer_progress;
var progress = $('#progress');
$.ajax ({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'plain',
    url: 'loadable.php' ,
    beforeSend: function(thisXHR)
        {
        timer_progress = setInterval(function()
            {
            if (thisXHR.readyState > 2)
                {
                var totalBytes = thisXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
                var dlBytes = thisXHR.responseText.length;
                progress
                    .attr('max', totalBytes)
                    .attr('value', dlBytes);
                }
            }, 200);
        },
    complete: function()
        {
        clearInterval(timer_progress);
        progress.attr('value', progress.attr('max'));
        },
    });

</script>
```

Первый файл в заголовке `Content-Length` посылает точную продолжительность операции в байтах, а по мере выполнения операции подает на вывод 1 байт — пробел.

Второй файл пытается загрузить первый (вялотянущийся) файл, по мере «скачивания» отображая, сколько байт из указанных в `Content-Length` загружено.